# Will a long running .net process be termintated if the user session is terminated?

Tags: c#, session, asp-classic, .net-4.5

I have a ASP C# application that allows users to upload and process text files. after the upload, the parser is called and starts its work. depending on the size and quantity of the files the user uploads, this process can run for up to 20 hours. If my users navigate away from the page, will that terminate the text processing? If so, is there a way to keep it running after the user leaves? I would like to setup some functionality to let them know when its complete.

Comment: If you are expecting termination, then you should deal with it in advance. E.g. organize processing in a transaction-like way and keep working queue and related data in persistent memory, deserializing it on application restart to continue job, etc.

Comment: Navigation from the site should not affect the execution of your code - when user closes his browser, there is no message sent to the server saying "Hey, JohnDoe has closed the browser, kill all his tasks now."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say: Start the text file processing in a separate thread, that way you won't have to consider things like the regular http request timeout (default 20 minutes) etc.

Regarding feedback to the users, do you expect them to stick around for 20 hours looking at the browser? If not, perhaps you could send them an email when the processing is completed? Otherwise you could implement some form of polling which allows the web browser to check back every (n) minutes to see if the processing of their text file has been completed.